# How to get a canvas element in leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I need to fill the polygon with texture using canvas. How can I get a polygon element to do this?

```
let latlngs = [
    [1714, 2549],
    [1776, 3336],
    [934, 3121],
    [836, 2382]
];

let myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5 });
let polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {renderer: myRenderer}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers and in particular https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern and/or https://github.com/cloudybay/leaflet-polygon-fillPattern

Comment: Thanks. None of the plugins solves my problem. I've already done it without canvas, only this is slowness. I just want to understand how to get a canvas element to draw.